# discord.Guild.id will only return <member 'id' of 'Guild' objects>

Tags: python, discord.py

I am attempting to teach myself how to use discord.py, and I am trying to make a bot that will be able to recognize which guild it received a command from, and refrence another file, so it can have individual presets per server, but my problem is that Guild.id does not seem to get the ID, and spits out <member 'id' of 'Guild' objects> in the shell, where I would expect the guild ID to be printed, and I am lost as to what could possibly be wrong.

The part I am not able to get work is only the last 'elif' prompt, but I added the rest of the code for more context, in case it is an error earlier in my code.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
#Bootup confirmation
    print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #Debugging reference
    print("{0.guild} - {0.author}: {0.content}".format(message))

    #Check if message is from bot and return if true
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    #Check if message contains $test and return a response
    elif message.content.startswith("$test"):
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")
        

    elif message.content.startswith("$id"):
        gid = discord.Guild.id
        print(gid)
```

Comment: You didn't set `discord.Guild.id` to anything and you don't need to... The message object contains the guild object as `message.guild` and of course the id is available as `message.guild.id`. Please check the docs for the [message model](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message)

Comment: I would advise you start using [discord.ext.commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)

Answer (score 0):

```py
guild_id = message.guild.id
```

I'd recommed you using [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) instead